# How to disable internet connection only for some standard user accounts in Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, internet-connection, internet-security

There are many users in my machine with Windows 7 Ultimate installed. Some of them are standard user accounts that have no administrative access to the computer. I want them to be unable to connect to the internet because of security issues. How to disable internet connection only for some standard user accounts in Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: Use the parental control maybe?

Comment: if you are using netgear router, use netgear app from android phone. it will be easy to block internet only to specific computers with out disturbing lan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Windows recommends using [Parental Controls](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/set-up-parental-controls)

---

Tweak internet explorer:

- Go to Internet Options in the Control Panel in the users account. Go to the Connections tab and click LAN settings. Uncheck "Automatically detect settings" and then check "Use proxy server" and put settings in for a proxy server that doesn't exist. eg 1.0.0.0 (1.1.1.1 is cloudflare dns) This will time out the Web browser each time a user tries to pull up an Internet site. Unfortunately, a savvy user could go into the settings and fix this.

---

User profile permission hacking (Medium)

- creating a new user profile and then choosing 'deny' on ntfs permissions for read and exectue on the executables for Mozilla,IE or Chrome, on that account.

Stops them from using internet, but MSN or any other pre isntalled messenger will still work.

---

- Using Group Policy Editor (Advanced)

Create new group and apply the policy

1. Create a new policy in GPMC by right-clicking your domain and pressing New. Name the policy No Internet. Or Press windows + R, the run windows will show, type in gpedit.msc
2. Right-click No Internet and press Enforced to check it.
3. Select No Internet in the left-hand pane, select Authenticated Users under Security Filtering and press Remove, and OK to 
   prevent the policy from applying.
4. Using Group Policy to implement Internet Explorer settings, navigate to User Configuration / Windows Settings / Internet Explorer 
   Maintenance in the No Internet policy.
5. Right-click Internet Explorer Maintenance and press Preference Mode. 
   NOTE: If a policy is already defined, you must press Reset Browser Settings, which will reset any Internet Explorer Maintenance 
   Group Policy, before you press Preference Mode.
6. Navigate through Connections and double-click Proxy Settings (Preference Mode).
7. Check Enable proxy Settings, Use the same proxy server for all addresses, and Do not use proxy server for local (intranet) 
   addresses.
8. Type 127.0.0.1 into Address of proxy and 80 into Port.
9. Press OK.
10. Close the No Internet group Policy.

**NOTE:**
To prevent a user from changing their proxy settings, implement Disable changing proxy settings or Disable the Connections page in the No Internet policy.

To prevent a user from accessing the internet.

1. Select the No Internet group Policy under your domain and press Add under Security Filtering.
2. Use the Advanced dialog to locate and select the user, pressing OK.
3. Press OK.
4. If the user is logged on, force the policy to update.

Comment: Just for anyone who is using the fake proxy method: I recommend not using 1.1.1.1, because this is now used as public DNS server. The easiest would be to use 127.0.0.1, like this you are not creating any network traffic at all.

Comment: Its wierd how I ran into that the other day and now I had to update this ... very old answer. wow - Thanks for the ping about that it has been updated

Comment: it is an old answer, but good and still valid - just got to it by searching google :-)

Comment: This will only block browser/HTTP traffic. It will also not work for any browser or application that uses its own proxy settings (Including one of the major ones, which I won't name because I don't think its wise to describe scurity bypasses in a public forum)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a foolproof way to do this on a local machine. There are few options you can consider but they can be circumvented if the user is technically adept. The following post describes such a method.

[Disable internet access in windows for specific user accounts](http://www.christianblog.com/blog/abelajohnb/disable-internet-access-in-windows-for-specific-user-accounts/)

Alternatively you can consider [Parental Controls](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Set-up-Parental-Controls)

Answer (score 0):

How to Remove Connection Tab from Internet Option through Group policy

If you want to prevent user to change Internet setting then this is very useful feature in Windows . with the help this feature you can prevent user to Add or Remove Dial Up connection and also VPN setting  and also Prevent to change LAN setting from Internet Option .

http://www.com-networks.com/2013/04/how-to-remove-connection-tab-from.html