# Disable internet access but leave LAN working regardless of the user privilege

Tags: networking, firewall, blocking, restrictions

I'm looking for a command (or command-line program) to toggle (disable/enable) internet access to the outside world in Windows 10 pro. It should temporarily block internet access but leave the LAN working.

I know it looks like the same question as others found in this site, but my question is how to do it even without the user having admin privilege.

If there is no way to make it in commands or changing settings, can you recommend other solution(firewall, USG..etc)

Thanks

Comment: You can create a Scheduled Task to preform an action with higher privilege than  the user's. See https://superuser.com/questions/770420/schedule-a-task-with-admin-privileges-without-a-user-prompt-in-windows-7

Comment: You need admin privileges to modify the routing table (what you want to do is remove the default gateway). If you can't get these on the computer you can implement it in a firewall in a router, combined with Mac/IP address filtering/whitelisting - I'd recommend a router flashed with dd-wrt, but this is not an "out the box" solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable internet connection only for some standard user accounts in Windows 7 Ultimate?](https://superuser.com/questions/379819/how-to-disable-internet-connection-only-for-some-standard-user-accounts-in-windo)

Comment: `route [add | delete] 0.0.0.0 ...`